# Creating a MvxMasterDetailPage in a MvvmCross project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, mvvmcross, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to write an app using `Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0`, `.net standard 2.0` libraries, and `MvvmCross.Forms 5.6.3` and I would like the main page to be a `MvxMasterDetailPage` which there seems to be very little documentation/samples for.

I created the `MxvMasterDetailPage` by adding a standard Xamarin `MasterDetailPage` to the project, changing the base class and then adding a `ViewModel` for it.

In the UWP app running on the desktop I cannot get the page to work as a main page because I get the error when I run:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required.
Parameter name: height
   at Windows.Foundation.Size..ctor(Double width, Double height)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.MasterDetailControl.get_MasterSize()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.MasterDetailPageRenderer.UpdateBounds()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.MasterDetailPageRenderer.OnNativeSizeChanged(Object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
```

However, when I add a `MvxContentPage` as the main page and navigate to the master detail page it does display the page.

The next problem I have is that the `MvxMasterDetailPage` seems to show one master detail page inside another as in this image:

[image: master detail control]

.. and when I view the live visual tree there does appear to be 2 master detail controls added to it:

[image]

Does anyone have a good example of the `MvxMasterDetailPage` working using `MvvmCross` in `.Net Standard` libraries?